# Griffon rest plugin giving org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser class not found ..

Tags: rest, griffon

First opportunity i've had to use Griffon in a real application and i'm following the GIA book trying the example with Griffon in the front and Grails in the back  .. I've build the app  but can't get the Griffon front end to run .. The code ..

```
void populateModel(model) {
    withRest(id: 'bookstoreREST',
            uri: 'http://localhost:8080/bookstore/') {
        def response = get(path: 'author')
```

is throwing java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xerces/parsers/AbstractSAXParser
    at groovyx.net.http.ParserRegistry.parseHTML(ParserRegistry.java:235)

which corresponds to the line defining the response .. I can access it directly from the background Grails app  .. Do i need to install something else other than the Rest plugin to make this work ? Currently using Griffon 1.5  ..

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

.. enabled  mavenCentral() in the BuildConfig.groovy project file  .. seems to work

Comment: if this works for you, that's great! Please consider explaining a bit in more detail, where to put that line, how to use it and why you think it seems to work. So that other readers have it easier to find that answer. In one or two days, then you'll be able to accept your own answer (unless you find another answer that you like more)